# Disable wifi power management

Tags: networking, wireless, suspend, power-management, reboot

#### Problems:

1) Power management makes Wifi connection unstable. I need to disable it completely
2) My wifi doesn't automatically turns on after sleep. I should do it myself

#### Info

Laptop:      Dell vostro 14-5480
OS:          Ubuntu 15.04
kernel:      3.19.0-30
Wifi-card:   Intel 7265
Wifi-driver: iwlwifi

#### What i've tried

"iwconfig wlan0 power off" helps but I should do it every time my Laptop turns on. I tried to play with /etc/pm. Nothing helped. The only solution was adding

> sleep 10
> iwconfig wlan0 poweroff
> exit 0

to /etc/rc.local. Now power management turns off, as I need, but only when I reboot/switch on laptop. If I turn my wifi on manually after suspend, I should also manually turn off power management.

I thought maybe [13.10 suspend kills wifi connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365441/13-10-suspend-kills-wifi-connection) solution might help, I made a file wakenet.sh, but it doesn't work and it shouldn't as ubuntu 15.04 doesn't have nmcli nm, so it's impossible to use

> nmcli nm sleep flase

At least I haven't found how to do it with new nmcli.

Maybe someone can help me at least in finding the proper alternative command instead of nmcli nm sleep false?

Comment: Doesn't `iwlwifi` default to power:off? From `modinfo iwlwifi`: `parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)`

Comment: I guess no, here is my output, when i try iwconfig http://pastebin.com/bMuyjVW3

Comment: What does this tell us? `cat /sys/module/iwlwifi/parameters/power_save`? We hope it is `N`.

Comment: Yes, it says exactly "N"

Answer (score 13):

The best solution that worked for me (in Ubuntu 16.04LTS) is to change the value of `wifi.powersave` located in `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` from `3` (enabled) to `2` (disabled).

This effectively makes the effects of `sudo iwconfig <interface> power off` permanent.

Source: [Power management for wireless unable to turn off in Xubunu 15.04 Vivid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606446/power-management-for-wireless-unable-to-turn-off-in-xubunu-15-04-vivid/865364#865364)

Answer (score 2):

there are a couple of options here:

> [How can I prevent iwconfig power management from being turned on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85214/how-can-i-prevent-iwconfig-power-management-from-being-turned-on)

The answer provided by Pierz worked for me:

> Another approach is to add an explicit directive (wireless-power) to control power management in the /etc/network/interfaces configuration file (e.g. Disable it for wlan0 with DHCP):
>
> ```
> auto wlan0 
> iface wlan0 inet dhcp
> wireless-power off
> ```

I am using:

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS  OS 
image: ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img
```