# Is there a way of increasing the wi-fi signal when using Linux?

Tags: drivers, wireless

On a Dell Vostro 5490 notebook, I have been having trouble making the Wi-fi work properly. For both Ubuntu 19.10 and Fedora 31, I have experienced the same issue. The computer gets to connect to the internet, but the signal is very weak. I imagine that it's something related to drivers because when using Windows, the Wi-fi works great.

I'm sending you the output for the commands `lspci`, `lsusb`, and `sudo iwlist scan && nmcli dev wifi list`

**EDIT 1:**

lspci output

```
Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
Serial controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Integrated Sensor Solution
USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462
Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
SATA controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SATA AHCI Controller
PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02bc (rev f0)
PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b4 (rev f0)
ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX250] (rev a1)
Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
Non-Volatile memory controller: Lite-On Technology Corporation Device 9100 (rev 03)
```

lsusb output

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5538 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 27c6:538d Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**EDIT 2:**
sudo iwlist scan && nmcli dev wifi list output

```
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning.

virbr0-nic  Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp0s20f3  Scan completed :
  Cell 01 - Address: 78:BA:F9:E5:F5:8C
            Channel:149
            Frequency:5.745 GHz
            Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
            Encryption key:on
            ESSID:"eduroam"
            Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                      36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
            Mode:Master
            Extra:tsf=000004997e052f7b
            Extra: Last beacon: 17ms ago
            IE: Unknown: 0007656475726F616D
            IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
            IE: Unknown: 071243412024041134041864051884031895051E
            IE: Unknown: 0B050500056E5B
            IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC191BFFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
            IE: Unknown: 3D1695000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: Unknown: 7F080010000001400041
            IE: Unknown: 851E05008F000F00FF035900773537323541343132000000000000000500004D
            IE: Unknown: 9606004096001400
            IE: Unknown: BF0CB279830FEAFF0000EAFF0000
            IE: Unknown: C005000000C0FF
            IE: Unknown: C3020002
            IE: WPA Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
            IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
            IE: Unknown: DD06004096010104
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960305
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960B09
            IE: Unknown: DD080040961301003401
            IE: Unknown: DD050040961405
  Cell 02 - Address: 78:BA:F9:E5:F5:83
            Channel:11
            Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
            Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
            Encryption key:on
            ESSID:"eduroam"
            Bit Rates:12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                      54 Mb/s
            Mode:Master
            Extra:tsf=000004997da750f1
            Extra: Last beacon: 17ms ago
            IE: Unknown: 0007656475726F616D
            IE: Unknown: 010698243048606C
            IE: Unknown: 03010B
            IE: Unknown: 0706434120010B1E
            IE: Unknown: 0B0501003D8D5B
            IE: Unknown: 2A0100
            IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC191BFFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
            IE: Unknown: 3D160B000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: Unknown: 7F080010000001400001
            IE: Unknown: 851E00008F000F00FF035900773537323541343132000000000000000100004E
            IE: Unknown: 9606004096000700
            IE: WPA Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
            IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
            IE: Unknown: DD06004096010104
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960305
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960B09
            IE: Unknown: DD080040961301003401
            IE: Unknown: DD050040961405
  Cell 03 - Address: 78:BA:F9:CB:10:23
            Channel:1
            Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
            Quality=24/70  Signal level=-86 dBm  
            Encryption key:on
            ESSID:"eduroam"
            Bit Rates:12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                      54 Mb/s
            Mode:Master
            Extra:tsf=00000499c46fc966
            Extra: Last beacon: 26392ms ago
            IE: Unknown: 0007656475726F616D
            IE: Unknown: 010698243048606C
            IE: Unknown: 030101
            IE: Unknown: 0706434120010B1E
            IE: Unknown: 0B050400378D5B
            IE: Unknown: 2A0100
            IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC191BFFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
            IE: Unknown: 3D1601000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: Unknown: 7F080010000001400001
            IE: Unknown: 851E04008F000F00FF035900773537323341353136000000000000000400004E
            IE: Unknown: 9606004096000700
            IE: WPA Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
            IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
            IE: Unknown: DD06004096010104
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960305
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960B09
            IE: Unknown: DD080040961301003401
            IE: Unknown: DD050040961405
  Cell 04 - Address: 78:BA:F9:CB:10:21
            Channel:1
            Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
            Quality=23/70  Signal level=-87 dBm  
            Encryption key:on
            ESSID:"UdeM avec cryptage"
            Bit Rates:12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                      54 Mb/s
            Mode:Master
            Extra:tsf=00000499c4706058
            Extra: Last beacon: 26392ms ago
            IE: Unknown: 00125564654D2061766563206372797074616765
            IE: Unknown: 010698243048606C
            IE: Unknown: 030101
            IE: Unknown: 050400010000
            IE: Unknown: 0706434120010B1E
            IE: Unknown: 0B050400378D5B
            IE: Unknown: 2A0100
            IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC191BFFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
            IE: Unknown: 3D1601000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: Unknown: 7F080010000001400001
            IE: Unknown: 9606004096000700
            IE: WPA Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
            IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
            IE: Unknown: DD06004096010104
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960305
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960B09
            IE: Unknown: DD080040961301003401
            IE: Unknown: DD050040961405
  Cell 05 - Address: 78:BA:F9:E5:F5:80
            Channel:11
            Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
            Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
            Encryption key:off
            ESSID:"UdeM non securise"
            Bit Rates:12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                      54 Mb/s
            Mode:Master
            Extra:tsf=000004997da6d53f
            Extra: Last beacon: 17ms ago
            IE: Unknown: 00115564654D206E6F6E207365637572697365
            IE: Unknown: 010698243048606C
            IE: Unknown: 03010B
            IE: Unknown: 0706434120010B1E
            IE: Unknown: 0B0501003D8D5B
            IE: Unknown: 2A0100
            IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC191BFFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: Unknown: 3D160B000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: Unknown: 7F080010000001400001
            IE: Unknown: 851E00008F000F00FF035900773537323541343132000000000000000100004E
            IE: Unknown: 9606004096000700
            IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
            IE: Unknown: DD06004096010104
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960305
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960B09
            IE: Unknown: DD080040961301003401
            IE: Unknown: DD050040961404
  Cell 06 - Address: 78:BA:F9:E5:F5:81
            Channel:11
            Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
            Quality=32/70  Signal level=-78 dBm  
            Encryption key:on
            ESSID:"UdeM avec cryptage"
            Bit Rates:12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                      54 Mb/s
            Mode:Master
            Extra:tsf=000004997da61776
            Extra: Last beacon: 17ms ago
            IE: Unknown: 00125564654D2061766563206372797074616765
            IE: Unknown: 010698243048606C
            IE: Unknown: 03010B
            IE: Unknown: 0706434120010B1E
            IE: Unknown: 0B0501003D8D5B
            IE: Unknown: 2A0100
            IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC191BFFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
            IE: Unknown: 3D160B000500000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: Unknown: 7F080010000001400001
            IE: Unknown: 9606004096000700
            IE: WPA Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
            IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
            IE: Unknown: DD06004096010104
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960305
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960B09
            IE: Unknown: DD080040961301003401
            IE: Unknown: DD050040961405
  Cell 07 - Address: 78:BA:F9:E5:F5:8F
            Channel:149
            Frequency:5.745 GHz
            Quality=25/70  Signal level=-85 dBm  
            Encryption key:off
            ESSID:"UdeM non securise"
            Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                      36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
            Mode:Master
            Extra:tsf=000004997e064b3b
            Extra: Last beacon: 17ms ago
            IE: Unknown: 00115564654D206E6F6E207365637572697365
            IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
            IE: Unknown: 071243412024041134041864051884031895051E
            IE: Unknown: 0B050500056E5B
            IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC191BFFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: Unknown: 3D1695000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: Unknown: 7F080010000001400041
            IE: Unknown: 851E05008F000F00FF035900773537323541343132000000000000000500004D
            IE: Unknown: 9606004096001400
            IE: Unknown: BF0CB279830FEAFF0000EAFF0000
            IE: Unknown: C005000000C0FF
            IE: Unknown: C3020002
            IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
            IE: Unknown: DD06004096010104
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960305
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960B09
            IE: Unknown: DD080040961301003401
            IE: Unknown: DD050040961404
  Cell 08 - Address: 78:BA:F9:E5:F5:8E
            Channel:149
            Frequency:5.745 GHz
            Quality=24/70  Signal level=-86 dBm  
            Encryption key:on
            ESSID:"UdeM avec cryptage"
            Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                      36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
            Mode:Master
            Extra:tsf=000004997e058d5c
            Extra: Last beacon: 17ms ago
            IE: Unknown: 00125564654D2061766563206372797074616765
            IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
            IE: Unknown: 071243412024041134041864051884031895051E
            IE: Unknown: 0B050500056E5B
            IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC191BFFFFFF0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
            IE: Unknown: 3D1695000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
            IE: Unknown: 7F080010000001400041
            IE: Unknown: 9606004096001400
            IE: Unknown: BF0CB279830FEAFF0000EAFF0000
            IE: Unknown: C005000000C0FF
            IE: Unknown: C3020002
            IE: WPA Version 1
                Group Cipher : TKIP
                Pairwise Ciphers (1) : TKIP
                Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
            IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
            IE: Unknown: DD06004096010104
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960305
            IE: Unknown: DD050040960B09
            IE: Unknown: DD080040961301003401
            IE: Unknown: DD050040961405
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you run a broadband speed test, are the up/down speeds different between Ubuntu and Windows? If so, what numbers did you get for both?

Comment: Have you checked to see if others in your vicinity are using the same wireless channel: $ nmcli -f common dev wifi

Comment: The Windows driver does a good job of autodetecting the active, stronger antenna connection; perhaps the iwlwifi Linux driver does not. Background: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-find-out-wireless-network-speed-signal-strength.html and https://askubuntu.com/q/1014198/197910   iwlwifi drivers are here https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html - Please open a terminal, run `sudo iwlist scan && nmcli dev wifi list` & copy the result. Come back here, click [edit] & paste the result into yr question.

Comment: I suspect that one of the two antenna connectors is loose. https://www.windowscentral.com/sites/wpcentral.com/files/styles/xlarge_wm_blb/public/field/image/2016/09/xps15-wifi-snap.jpg?itok=HKwvhTr9 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Run the https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info scrip.