# Why does Ubuntu takes so long to reconnect to the Wifi after Suspend mode compared to Windows on the same machine?

Tags: wireless, network-manager, suspend

I'm on Ubuntu 20.10, on Dell XPS 13 9370, with a Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 wifi card, using the ath10k driver. This laptop, with this configuration, is known to be well supported under Linux/Ubuntu (Dell even sells this machine with Ubuntu preinstalled).

In Ubuntu, it takes +/- 10 seconds after resume from suspend to connect to the wifi (not a big deal, but annoying since many apps wake up complaining about lack of network connection).

In Windows 10, on the same machine, the reconnection after suspend is instant.

I've tried various settings to improve wifi reconnection speed, with limited results. For reference, here's what I've tried:

- Disabling wifi power management: [Disable wifi power management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695867/disable-wifi-power-management)
- Replacing wpa_supplicant with iwd: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/call-for-testing-improved-wifi-via-iwd/17795

I'm just curious to know if there's a possible tweak that I'm missing (in network manager, systemd, some suspend script or?) to speed this up.

Any idea someone?

Comment: I have the same problem as you. I use Dell XPS 7590. Have you managed to solve that problem? It worked perfectly on Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I have the same problem with a Dell XPS laptop that has this network card `02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)` with Ubuntu version `NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 21.04"
VERSION_ID="21.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=hirsute
UBUNTU_CODENAME=hirsute`