# WiFi adapter not found ubuntu 21.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, 21.10

Since a while back, I've had issues with my wifi. It started a month ago when I was using ubuntu 20.04. I've updated to ubuntu 21.10 since but the issue remains. The problem is that the wifi abruptly turns off after a while (sometimes a few seconds after booting, sometimes a few hours) and that it disappears from the menu and display wifi adapter not found in the settings. I know this is a common issue but I haven't been able to solve it.

[Wireless info when wifi adapter is found](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/YZJJsytynf/)

[Wireless info when wifi adapter is not found](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kKrvnmMnyg/)

Update:

I'm using an intel open-source driver that is supposed to work.
I've tried disabling secure boot in the BIOS, updating the BIOS to the latest version. I've also tried disabling wifi power management. Nothing works. Although it feels as if the wifi-dissapears less frequently there are still issues.

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIos. After that, try command: sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall. Reboot.  Also check "Additional drivers" in Softare&Updates.

Comment: Thank you, currently trying to disable the secure boot. It works thus far but that doesn't have to mean anything yet. The other stuff returned that all drivers are already installed and that no additional drivers are available (which is what it returned before as well).

Comment: @Emvo `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` is for other proprietary drivers, namely Nvidia's. The suggestion about looking in additional drivers is fine but not applicable: If the WiFi needed something not previously installed it wouldn't work. And Intel network devices, ALL of them, work woth open-source drivers already installed and running.

Comment: @gertrud.leijonhufvud You have "power management" enabled which the most probable culprit. Check the answers here https://askubuntu.com/questions/695867/disable-wifi-power-management

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you! Once again I can't tell if it works immediately but it seems reasonable and I haven't tried it before. Should I enable secure boot again though? I'm guessing that the point of that is to get access to other drivers but the current driver is supposed to work.

Comment: Secure Boot has nothing to do with this, it doesn't matter if enabled or disabled. It prevents loading proprietary drivers unless manually signed but, again, Intel's are open-source. If you've been using the computer with SB enabled without noticing some hardware not working or messages at the boot asking you to define a MOK password then, in your case, SB is irrelevant. You may want to disable it for convenience if, for example, you decide to use virtualization (Virtualbox, VMWare, etc.) because the software tends to install additional (virtual) drivers that will then be intercepted.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue years ago, and it turned out to be a bugged power saving mode.

In `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`, change `wifi.powersave = 3` to `wifi.powersave = 2` to disable it and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I've tried it and I'm still having issues (although it fells like they're not as common) :(