# How to disable wifi power save using netplan yaml configuration?

Tags: networking, netplan

I need to disable the wifi power save option using netplan configuration files. I tried adding

> powersave: False

It didn't work.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think netplan or any other part of network configuration can do this.  You have to create a module config file to disable power saving in the device driver.  You didn't mention anything about your network device in your question.  `ip` and `ethtool -i` can get this information.

Comment: I've tried multiple things, only `iwconfig Wlso1 power off` has worked so far. I need to run it every time after boot. Without `powersave disabled` experience is very poor.

Comment: You should put the iwconfig command in your question instead of in a comment.  It would also help to add the output from `ethtool -i Wlso1` to your question.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently

Comment: @user10489 I've tried the accepted solution of the question you mentioned. It is not working. I need solution using netplan as it is the default way to manage network in the ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable wifi power management](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695867/disable-wifi-power-management)

Comment: Already tried that. On rebooting the system, it power management remain enabled despite using rc.local .